# Understanding ngResource and UI Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to use a modal window (UI Bootstrap) to update documents in a Mongo datastore and am interested in determining the different ways for doing so.

Currently I have a view that, by way of it's associated controller, iterates through a list of documents that gets returned from the database (via $resource) and creates a button for each item. Each button opens a modal instance with it's own controller. I pass the item (an object) to the modal instance controller so that I can display some of it's current properties through a form in the modal window.

What I am looking for are ways to update this item with changed values.

Should the modal instance controller do the saving? Should I pass an updated object back to the calling controller and update from there?

Also, if I used .query() to get a list of documents but only pass one to the modal instance controller, how can I perform an update on that particular document without having to look up the _id and do a .get() on it?